# What is a "valley block"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

A line from [*The Water Diviner* (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Water_Diviner)

> I hit water at 15 feet. Bit brackish, but good pressure. With water we'll be able to put stock in that **valley block**.

"Block mountain" is a term referring to "a mountain formed by the uplift of blocks of the earth's crust." ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/block-mountain)) I could see "valley block" referring to a similar concept having something to do with earth's tectonic plates or crust. But I can't find a dictionary definition on this.

Comment: The link to wikipedia provides no clue to the question. Without further context, I would guess that the quote refers to an area where one might put "stock", which could be housing or animals, where there needs to be a water supply. And, maybe it's to be in a valley. The connection to tectonic plates seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I took ["stock"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stock) to be short for "livestock", which makes sense in a context where wells and water are discussed. I couldn't find a publicly available video clip for reference. Otherwise I'd have linked it.

Comment: I recall reading an old stories where ranchers would find a valley with steep walls and block its mouth with a short fence to keep their livestock inside. Maybe that’s a “valley block”?